# Turtle Graphics "if touching colour"

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a program in Turtle that draws a Christmas Tree and then some baubles, which I want to be placed randomly on the tree. However because a Christmas Tree is an irregular shape I am not able to place the baubles by randomly choosing x and y co-ordinates. Is there a way to randomly place the baubles on the tree?
I was considering an "turtle.pendown()" and then "if turtle.pen touching "green"" but I am not sure how to code this. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SO is not a code writing service - please see [ask] for why this question is not properly asked.  And, you didn't even bother to take the 2-minute site [tour].

Answer (score 2):

One simple, graphic, approach is to:

1. Find a Python module that has a [routine for performing the "point
   in polygon"
   inclusion](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~mac/e-stuff/point_in_polygon.py)
   test
2. Use turtle's `begin_poly()`, `end_poly()`, and `get_poly()` to capture the
   vertices that your code generates when drawing the tree
3. Randomly generate ornaments within the bounding box of the tree but
   also apply the crossing number test to see if their centers are on
   the tree

Here's an example implementation using an (exceptionally) abstract tree and ornaments:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randrange, choice
from point_in_polygon import cn_PnPoly

screen = Screen()

WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

COLORS = ["red", "yellow", "gold", "blue", "white", "pink"]

def draw_abstract_tree(turtle):
    width = WINDOW_WIDTH//4

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(0, -WINDOW_HEIGHT//4)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(8):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(150)
        turtle.forward(1.156 * width)
        turtle.right(150)
        width *= 0.9

    turtle.left(210)

    for _ in range(8):
        turtle.forward(1.156 * width)
        turtle.left(150)
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.right(150)
        width /= 0.9

    turtle.goto(0, -WINDOW_HEIGHT//4)

    turtle.setheading(0)

def decorate_tree(turtle, polygon):
    turtle.penup()

    for _ in range(1000):
        x = randrange(-WINDOW_WIDTH/4, WINDOW_WIDTH/4)
        y = randrange(-WINDOW_HEIGHT/4, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        diameter = randrange(1, 12)

        if cn_PnPoly((x, y), polygon):
            turtle.goto(x, y)
            turtle.color(choice(COLORS))
            turtle.dot(diameter)

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)
yertle.speed("fastest")
yertle.color("darkgreen")

yertle.begin_poly()
draw_abstract_tree(yertle)
yertle.end_poly()

polygon = yertle.get_poly()

yertle.begin_fill()
draw_abstract_tree(yertle)
yertle.end_fill()

decorate_tree(yertle, polygon)

screen.exitonclick()
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think `turtle` doesn't have method to check color.

But `turtle` uses `Canvas` from `tkinter` which have function `find_overlaping(rectangle)` to check if some objects overlaps this rectangle. Maybe it could works. Maybe you could check if there is tree in some small rectange in random place.

- [turtle.getcanvas()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.getcanvas)
- [tkinter: Canvas.find_overlapping()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_overlapping-method)